# Implement Chart.js Plugin Meteor Project

Tags: javascript, meteor, chart.js

i have a meteor project mit chart.js v2.5 at the client.

i want to use the following plugin.

[Chartjs Plugin](https://github.com/AlbinoDrought/chartjs-plugin-downsample)

I'm new to javascript and i can't find the way how to implement this plugin in chartjs on the client side.

can somebody help me with this?

thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may load the script on the server and then include it in your html (as in the example [downsample samples](https://github.com/AlbinoDrought/chartjs-plugin-downsample/blob/master/samples/data.html)) ...

```
<head>
  <title>Scatter Chart</title>
  <script src="../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="../chartjs-plugin-downsample.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, you may take the source of the script and place it in the JavaScript of your page.

In either case, then add the downsample settings in the options section ...

```
options: {
    downsample: {
        enabled: true,
        threshold: 500 // max number of points to display per dataset
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, the best way to use chart.js in Meteor is to use the chart.js NPM package.  Run `meteor npm install chart.js --save` from the command line to import the chart.js package.  Then to use chart.js on a client page add a chart.js import and instantiate the chart from the Template `onRendered` callback.

If your chart depends on data from a published collection, then you must first ensure that the subscription is complete, then render the chart after (using `Tracker.afterFlush()`).  Here is an example showing all of these elements together.

Template file:

```
<template name="kpi_application_status">
  <canvas id="kpiApplicationStatus"></canvas>
</template>
```

Template definition:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Kpis } from '../../../api/kpis/kpis.js';
import { Chart } from 'chart'

import './kpi-application-status.html';

var buildChart = function() {
  var kpi = Kpis.find({kpi_type: 'application_status'});

  if (kpi.count() > 0) {
    var labels = [];
    var data = [];
    var color = [];

    kpi.forEach((record) => {
      record.kpis.forEach((item) => {
        labels.push(item.status);
        data.push(item.count);

        switch(item.status) {
          case 'Unvalidated':
            color.push('#FD625E');
            break;
          case 'Validated':
            color.push('#01a982');
            break;
        }
      });
    });

    var chartData = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: data,
          backgroundColor: color,
          hoverBackgroundColor: color
        }
      ]
    };

    var kpiApplicationStatus = this.$('#kpiApplicationStatus');
    var doughnutChart = new Chart(kpiApplicationStatus, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: chartData,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
          labels: {
                        generateLabels: function(chart) {
                            var data = chart.data;
                            if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
                                return data.labels.map(function(label, i) {
                                    var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
                                    var ds = data.datasets[0];
                                    var arc = meta.data[i];
                                    var custom = arc.custom || {};
                                    var getValueAtIndexOrDefault = Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault;
                                    var arcOpts = chart.options.elements.arc;
                                    var fill = custom.backgroundColor ? custom.backgroundColor : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.backgroundColor, i, arcOpts.backgroundColor);
                                    var stroke = custom.borderColor ? custom.borderColor : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderColor, i, arcOpts.borderColor);
                                    var bw = custom.borderWidth ? custom.borderWidth : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderWidth, i, arcOpts.borderWidth);

                                    return {
                                        text: label + " (" + ds.data[i] + ")",
                                        fillStyle: fill,
                                        strokeStyle: stroke,
                                        lineWidth: bw,
                                        hidden: isNaN(ds.data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,

                                        // Extra data used for toggling the correct item
                                        index: i
                                    };
                                });
                            } else {
                                return [];
                            }
                        }
                    }
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'label'
        },
        showAllTooltips: true
      }
    });
  }
};

Template.kpi_application_status.onRendered(function() {
  this.subscribe('chartData', 'application_status', () => {
    Tracker.afterFlush(() => {
      buildChart();
    })
  });
});
```

Since you are also trying to use an additional chart.js plugin, you just make sure you also import that corresponding NPM package as well using the same command line approach:

```
meteor npm install chartjs-plugin-downsample --save
```

Comment: In case this helps anybody else; I had the error "Error: Cannot find module 'chart'", which was fixed by either using require instead of import at the top of my js file: const Chart = require('chart.js'); or by adding 'js' to the import: import { Chart } from 'chart.js';